# Chrome %5C resolving as /

Tags: google-chrome, url, backslash

I am working with a API that is requesting a Windows domain/username, but Chrome keeps resolving backslashes "/" as forward slashes "\"  I've tried \\ and %5C, but chrome keeps resolving these as "/".  Is there any way around this?

```
Typed URL:
http://localhost:59244/api/UsersAPI/TESTDOMAIN%5Ctestuser

Error message:
Requested URL      http://localhost:59244/api/UsersAPI/TESTDOMAIN/testuser
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This previous question has a lot of information on invalid or unwise URL characters:
[Which characters make a URL invalid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547899/which-characters-make-a-url-invalid)

From the link:

> List of unwise characters are allowed but may cause problems:
>
> `unwise      = "{" | "}" | "|" | "\" | "^" | "[" | "]" | "`"`

I think Chrome is trying to fix your URL "mistake" for you. Does the API have a method that would accept the account name in a POST body?

The API should provide some sort of documentation on how it's expecting to receive the account name. I don't think you are ever going to be able to reliably send the backslash character.